# how is asyncio.sleep() in python implemented?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm a newbie python3 enthusiast, who hopes to find out how asyncio.sleep() is implemented by the library.

I'm capable of writing coroutines but I can't seem to think about how to start writing code for asynchronous sleep.

would be great if you share the code directly or give a quick tutorial on how to find the code on my local machine. thank you!

Comment: Is your goal to find the actual production code of `asyncio.sleep`, or do you want to understand how to write one yourself? The former is more involved than one would expect due to the many concerns covered by the library (e.g. cancellation, the [special-casing of `sleep(0)`](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284), the option to provide a result value, etc.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For code implemented in Python (as opposed to C extensions), if you're using `ipython`, an easy way to see the source code is to use the `??` operator. For example, on my 3.6 install:

```
In [1]: import asyncio

In [2]: asyncio.sleep??
Signature: asyncio.sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None)
Source:
@coroutine
def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay == 0:
        yield
        return result

    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    h = future._loop.call_later(delay,
                                futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                                future, result)
    try:
        return (yield from future)
    finally:
        h.cancel()
File:      c:\program files\python36\lib\asyncio\tasks.py
Type:      function
```

You can also just [look at the CPython GitHub repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib/), but depending on the code organization it may not be obvious where to look (e.g. in this case the code actually exists in `asyncio.tasks`, and is auto-imported into `asyncio`), while `ipython` magic finds it for you directly.

Comment: It didnt occur to me to use the call_later function which I have experimented with previously. really appreciated, thank you!