# Python Asyncio confusion between asyncio.sleep() and time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-asyncio

From the documentation, if we want to implement a non-blocking delay we should implement `await asyncio.sleep(delay)` because `time.sleep(delay)` is blocking in nature. But from what I could understand, it is the `await` keyword that cedes control of the thread to do something else while the function `f()` following the keyword i.e. `await f()` finishes its calculations.

So if we need the `await` keyword in order for `asyncio.sleep(delay)` to be non-blocking, what is the difference with its counterpart `time.sleep(delay)` if both are not awaited for?

Also, can't we reach the same result by preceding both sleep functions with a `await` keyword?

Comment: `await time.sleep(delay)` raises a `TypeError` because `time.sleep` returns `None` and you can't `await None`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asyncio.sleep() vs time.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/asyncio-sleep-vs-time-sleep)

Answer (score 1):

From one answer of somewhat similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493718):

> The function asyncio.sleep simply registers a future to be called in x seconds while time.sleep suspends the execution for x seconds.

So the execution of that coroutine called `await asyncio.sleep()` is suspended until event loop of asyncio revokes after timer-expired event.

However, `time.sleep()` literally blocks execution of *current thread* until designated time is passed, preventing chance to run either an event loop or other tasks while waiting - which makes concurrency possible despite being *single threaded*.

For what I understand that's difference of following:

1. *counting X seconds with stopwatch **yourself***
2. *let the **clock** ticking and periodically check if X seconds has passed*

You, a `thread` probably can't do other thing while looking at stopwatch yourself, while you're free to do other jobs between periodic check on latter case.

---

Also, you can't use synchronous functions with `await`.

From [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) that implements `await` and `async`:

> `await`, similarly to `yield from`, suspends execution of read_data **coroutine** until db.fetch awaitable completes and returns the result data.

You can't suspend normal subroutine, python is imperative language.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, can't we reach the same result by preceding both sleep functions with a `await` keyword?

No, that's the thing. `time.sleep()` *blocks*. You call it, then nothing will happen for a while, then your program will resume when the function returns. You can `await` at that point all you want, there's nothing to await.

`asyncio.sleep()` *returns* immediately, and it returns an *awaitable*. When you `await` that awaitable, the event loop will transfer control to another async function (if there is one), and crucially it will be notified when the awaitable is done, and resume the awaiting function at that point.

To illustrate what an awaitable is:

```
foo = asyncio.sleep()
print('Still active')
await foo
print('After sleep')
```

An awaitable is an object that can be `await`ed. You aren't awaiting the *function call*, you're awaiting its return value. There's no such return value with `time.sleep`.