# Asyncio python: How to call object methods in coroutines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm currently trying to do something like this:

```
import asyncio

class Dummy:
    def method(self):
        return 1
    def __str__(self):
        return "THIS IS A DUMMY CLASS"

async def start_doing():
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    return Dummy


async def do_something():
    return start_doing().method()


async def main():
    a = asyncio.create_task(do_something())
    b = asyncio.create_task(do_something())

    results = await asyncio.gather(a, b)
    print(results)

asyncio.run(main())
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Which indicates that I cannot call my method on a coroutine object. One way to fix this is by doing these:

```
async def do_something():
    return (await start_doing()).method()
```

But I think that by doing this you are inherently making your code synchronous. You are not generating a future, rather waiting for your work to be finished in `do_something` and then proceed to the next item in the queue.

How should I call an object method in the future when the `awaitable` has been awaited and my object is ready? how to schedule it to be called in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Await the call then call the method on an instance of the returned class.

```
async def start_doing():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return Dummy


async def do_something():
    thing = await start_doing()
    return thing().method()
```

---

> How should I call an object method in the future when the awaitable has been awaited and my object is ready? how to schedule it to be called in the future?

See if I can get this correct.

- When you create the task `do_something` it is scheduled.
- Eventually the event loop decides to let `do_something` start.
- `do_something` calls `start_doing` and awaits it.
- While `do_something` is waiting the event loop takes control away from it and lets something else have a turn.
- At some points in time `start_doing` is scheduled, started, finishes waiting/sleeping, returns the object

  - during the waiting/sleeping part control may have been transferred to other tasks by the event loop
- Eventually after `do_something` is done waiting the event loop gives control/focus back to it.

  - implies that other scheduled tasks have finished or are waiting on something.

I really don't know what the scheduling algorithm is, I think of it as a round-robin affair but it might be more intelligent than that.

Comment: Wouldn't using `await` make the coroutine wait for the result of called function and as a result run it in a blocking manner?

Comment: Note that you could also write `(await start_doing())().method()` (but I still prefer the more verbose approach proposed by this answer).

Comment: No, using `await ` is what makes it non blocking. When you call `await x` you simply say "I'm waiting for `x` feel free to schedule something else".

Comment: @cglacet - I rolled back your edit - returning an instance from `start_doing` would have broken `do_something`.

Comment: Yes, sorry I just saw that, that just looked weird, and my comment doesn't make sense in that scenario either :D. Ah, I've been able to edit, just in time.

Comment: .. Don't be sorry - feel free to edit my answers if you see something that needs it - I always get the chance to review.

Comment: @FarhoodET - see if my edit addresses your question.

Comment: *I think - when start_doing is called the event loop schedules it because it is a coroutine.* - this part is incorrect, the awaited coroutine gets executed immediately without going through an event loop cycle. It is only if a coroutine in the await chain chooses to *suspend* that the whole call chain is suspended and the event loop gets a chance to run. (The assumption that `await` always drops to the event loop sometimes causes bugs, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816319/1600898).)

Comment: Thank you @user4815162342 - so in this case the awaited coroutine executes immediately when it is called then because **it** awaits something then it's caller also has to wait and control drops back to the event loop.?  Nice link. Is that buried in the docs someplace or inferred from a bunch of stuff in the docs?

Comment: ..From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading) - `While a Task is running in the event loop, no other Tasks can run in the same thread. When a Task executes an await expression, the running Task gets suspended, and the event loop executes the next Task.` - The Next Task must then be the called coroutine being awaited..?

Comment: @wwii The task docs are imprecise here, sadly. The running task does get suspended, but only if the awaited expression actually *suspends*. If it can provide the data immediately, it does so, and the task doesn't drop to the event loop. (The `busy_loop` example proves it, as does the issue in the original question.) It should probably be reported as a doc issue.

Comment: @user4815162342 - last one I promise - 1) the awaited expression, or an *await chain* is all wrapped in the same Task? 2) It is the Task that cedes control to the event loop?. I'm going to comment on https://bugs.python.org/issue39085.

Comment: A task is how asyncio runs a coroutine. So yes, if a coroutine awaits another coroutine, that is still the same task. (And that other coroutine can in turn await another one, and so on; this stack of awaits is what I referred to as an await chain.) The bottom-most coroutine suspending will automatically suspend the whole task. Take a look at [this lecture](https://youtu.be/7JtNiwCH_OA) for a more in-depth explanation of await.

Answer (score 1):

To further extend on [@wwii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823755/wwii)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625400/1720199) and address the concerns about risk of blocking using `await` you can play with functions like the following `f`:

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio

start = datetime.now()

async def f(x, block_for=3):
    print(f"{x} IN     {ellapsed_time()}s")
    time.sleep(block_for)
    print(f"{x} AWAIT  {ellapsed_time()}s")
    await asyncio.sleep(x)
    print(f"{x} OUT    {ellapsed_time()}s")
    
def ellapsed_time():
    return (datetime.now() - start).seconds
    

asyncio.create_task(f(2))
asyncio.create_task(f(1))
```

Which produces:

```py
2 IN     0s
2 AWAIT  3s
1 IN     3s
1 AWAIT  6s
2 OUT    6s
1 OUT    7s
```

Until `await` is called, `f(2)` is blocking (preventing any other task from being scheduled). Once we call `await` we explicitly inform the scheduler that we are waiting for something (usually I/O, but here [simply "sleeping"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62493718/1720199)). Similarly, `f(1)` blocks `f(2)` from going out until it calls `await`.

If we remove the blocking part (block for 0s) `f(1)` will be rescheduled to execute before `f(2)` and will therefore finish first:

```py
>>> start = datetime.now()
>>> asyncio.create_task(f(2, block_for=0))
>>> asyncio.create_task(f(1, block_for=0))

2 IN     0s
2 AWAIT  0s
1 IN     0s
1 AWAIT  0s
1 OUT    1s
2 OUT    2s
```

Finally, about this part:

> … how to schedule it to be called in the future?

You can have a look at [how is asyncio.sleep() in python implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026721/1720199), it will probably help you understand better how asynchronous programming work.